# Fusion Table sync with google spreadsheet

Tags: mysql, svn, google-sheets, google-fusion-tables

I'm trying to sync my google spreadsheet with the fusion table, but I'm getting this error.

Problem running SQL:

> INSERT INTO 1AB09C-nASIxDE89CXOWoipT-CzHSSg31NOQwPMHv
>   ('Timestamp','Age','Name','Location') VALUES ('3/15/2016
>   14:27:27','1000','test','manila'): Exception: Access Not Configured.
>   The API (Fusion Tables API) is not enabled for your project. Please
>   use the Google Developers Console to update your configuration.. (line
>   311, file "Code")

I'm following the steps from this link:
https://fusion-tables-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/FusionTablesFormSync/docs/reference.html

This is weird because I enabled the Fusion Table API in the Developers Console.

I will appreciate any help.
Many thanks in advance

Comment: Hi all, Here's another problem that I'm encountering..Exception: Invalid query: ROWID must contain only numerals and underscores: '-1'. (line 308, file "Code")...Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to register your Fusion Table API on the [Console Developer](https://console.developers.google.com) and also click on the switch:

[image: Image where to click]

Answer (score 0):

Many Thanks for the help.
This is working now. I just followed the instructions from this link:
https://fusion-tables-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/FusionTablesFormSync/docs/reference.html

Proper setting of the triggers solved the problem.